# ASP.NET MVC 3 in production?

Tags: production, asp.net-mvc-3

Now that ASP.NET MVC 3 is in beta, and ready for "[go-live](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/06/announcing-nupack-asp-net-mvc-3-beta-and-webmatrix-beta-2.aspx)". Would it be safe to use in project, although not prevented I am curious on security, performance and ease of upgrade to release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using it in a project, but I couldn't get [Dependency Injection working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942976/unity-ioc-and-mvc-3-beta-passing-irepository-to-controller-constructor) (using Unity).  I was liking Razor, but the lack of intellisense did hurt my productivity.

I am sticking with MVC 2 for now.  When this is more documentation on Razor available, I will probably upgrade to 3.

EDIT:
Check out this [article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/10/MVC-3-Beta).  If you don't care about DI, then you might be all set.  The only other change was the validation model.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate sharing your experience. I am really appealed by the Razor view engine. I can live without the dependency injection and would rather not have to upgrade the views to Razor later, so I may make the jump.